# $A^{-1}XB = I$ Solve for X matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

$A^{-1}XB = I$, $A$ and $B$ are given and they are square matrixes.

If I want to solve this matrix equation for $X$, I need to change it to the form like this $X = A×B×I$?

Comment: Is $B$ invertible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $B$ is invertible, i.e. $B^{-1}$ exists, then, multiplying by $A$ from the left and by $B^{-1}$ from the right, you have:

\begin{equation}
A^{-1}XB = I\iff X=AA^{-1}XBB^{-1} = AIB^{-1}=AB^{-1},
\end{equation}

using that $AI=A$, respectively $IB^{-1}=B^{-1}$.

Comment: Latex/Mathjax tip: `P \iff Q` produces $P \iff Q$.

Comment: What if $B$ isn't invertible? $I$ doesn't have to be a square matrix. There'so no context.

Comment: Consider that the asker is a new contributor. Even though the context is missing, it is legitimate to guess what the student wants to ask... This does not make my answer less accurate, as I clearly stated: If $B$ is invertible...

Comment: Yes, A and B are square matrixes, sorry for not mentioning it.

Comment: BTW: an often used criterion to check whether a matrix is invertible is calculating its determinant. The matrix is invertible iff its determinant is not equal $0$.